# CC 1.75 MC 1.7.10: Creating a program which has an exception "program run something"

Tags: computercraft

So I have not tried anything yet, but I know those code scripts wont work..
So my though was creating a program wich had some functions ex. `rm`, `delete`, `mkdir` and `edit`. So all of these programs have something in common, they all have an "exception", like a file name.. So I wondered how the programs actually can handle it, so what I though in the first place was something in an another language, but now what I think it would be in LUA as it is not is this:

Runned in shell: `MyProgram run DNS_SERVER`
   
MyProgram

```
local MyProgramexception = read(MyProgram {$0}:{$1}:{$2})
```

---

But it I guess it is not that simple, but what I need is something that run `if` statements for example like:

```
public $0 = {exception}
public $1 = {exception}
local run = ({$0}, run)
local del = ({$0}, rm)
local program = ({$1}, dns_server || web_server || other_things..)
```

This is of course some NON WORKING code as I tried to look as real as possible..

---

So I wondered if there is someone out there who actually knows this?

---

Also posted on Arqade, but it was off-topic somehow..

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit a vague question to me (and some vague non-lua code), but I think you mean program *arguments*, like this:

```
rename <argument1> <argument2>
```

To accomplish this, you can store all arguments in a table like this:

```
local arg = {...}
```

the `...` does the magic. Now, you can access argument #1 by doing this:

```
arg[1]
```

I hope I have understood your question well.